# Flutterwave card payment shows 'Payload needs 3DES-24 Encryption' message. I am sending customer credit card details for payment

Tags: java, rest, flutterwave

I am using flutterwave payment gateway for payment using card. I am sending card details to flutterwave and getting following message:

```
"Payload needs 3DES-24 Encryption"
```

What should I do? How can encrypt card data using 3DES-24 encryption?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may need to encrypt your card details before you send them.

https://developer.flutterwave.com/v3.0/docs/encryption

Also important is to send the request as JSON, by adding this header to your request:

`'Content-Type':'application/json'`